# Access NavigationLink using accessibility identifier in XCTestCases class - SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, swiftui-navigationlink, xctestcase

I have recently started work on the SwiftUI framework, I'm writing UI Test Cases using XCTest.

```
NavigationLink("Login", destination: TabBarDashboardView())
          .accessibility(identifier: "linkLogin")
          .frame(width: 200, height: 50, alignment: .center)
          .foregroundColor(.white)
          .background(Color.red)
          .padding([.top, .bottom], 40)
```

In the XCTestCase class, I tried the following code to tap NavigationLink:

```
func testLoginActionAndNavigation() throws {
        let linkLogin = self.app.navigationBars.links["linkLogin"]
        linkLogin.tap()
        XCTAssertEqual(linkLogin.title, "linkLogin")
    }
```

I'm getting the following error and test case is getting failed:

`Failed to get matching snapshot: No matches found for Descendants matching type Link from input {( NavigationBar, identifier: '_TtGC7SwiftUI19UIHosting' )}`

I search related to NavigationLink access in XCTestCase class, but didn't find any valid/proper documentation.

Would you please help me on this if anyone already worked on this topic.

Comment: Any update?....

Answer (score 1):

Instead of looking for a matching `xxx.links[...]` element [which I believe is actually for clicking links inside a WebView], try:

```
 let linkLogin = self.app.otherElements.buttons["linkLogin"]
```

(I basically hit your same issue, and after trying a bunch of things finally ended up doing a [recording](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/ToolsLanguages/Conceptual/Xcode_Overview/RecordingUITests.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010215-CH75-SW1) and seeing what it same back with).

Comment: Sadly, this method does not work for me.